# Convert String in JavaScript to an Object

Tags: javascript

I like to convert the following string

```
"\nStructure=xyz\nIds=123,456,678,235"
```

to an object

```
{
    "Structure": "xyz",
    "Id": "123,456,678,235"
}
```

What is the best way?

Comment: To tell you the best way, we will need your attempt so we can compare with it

Comment: convert that into a json

Comment: Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Simply asking `What is the best way?` is primarily opinion based.

Comment: regex regex baby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`split()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPodTolZrUAhVLtY8KHRXvC7QQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit&usg=AFQjCNGVGuY9DfI9VAkeEZ1pZRBFS8cyUg&sig2=F9zgwItBXhLmf45Rwdxwcw) used for split the string by delimiter `\n`  and [`Array#forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj11biGlprUAhUBo48KHSe9CwIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNFWWfwOQKjXdfPWyAU9FxufcTqwMg&sig2=AjD4-NKxLZveeXp8r1B94g) method used for iterate the Array after the split string

```js
var a="\nStructure=xyz\nIds=123,456,678,235";
var one = a.trim().split('\n');
var res ={};
one.forEach(a=> res[a.split('=')[0]]=a.split('=')[1])
//one.forEach(function(a){ res[a.split('=')[0]]=a.split('=')[1]}) for IE or unsupported Arrow function
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Tu run this with IE use `function(a){}` since `(a)=>` not supported